# Extending Array<T> causing Flow InferError - Array not recognized as an interface

Tags: flowtype

I am trying to extend the Array interface but am running into the following Flow InferError:
"Cannot implement 'Array' because it is not an interface"

Here's a really simple example which causes the error:

```js
export interface MyIArray<T> extends Array<T> {
}

function foo() {
    const list: MyIArray<any> = [];
}
```

In this example, Flow is upset with the const list declaration.

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgWQE8BJAQSik0IB4AVAPjlFSQBMBnOcymhuAbwBQAX0GD0AVyTYYCCEjjoIEABQBKAYLja42ee3gAbBAYBcBEtyrVMSQowC8cANoBdANwigA).

Comment: Array is a [class](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/core.js#L242) not interface

Comment: So the [mobx type for IObservableArray](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/63b5ebcb1e1c89dc1fcdbd5adba97d14761f56d1/flow-typed/mobx.js#L111) is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this should be a comment but the Try Flow link is too long:

It looks like the mobx type for `IObservableArray` a bug. I copied over the relevant types from that file you linked and tried to declare an array variable as an `IObservableArray` and Flow complains ([Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEDMBsHsHcFoAuBPADgUwCbALbQEYAeAUAJYB2i6ATuAIYDG6oAkgILXV3IDCAFnXIBzdAB4AKgD5QAb2KgFoFBgBcoAEQBXVJjpV1AGnmKCAK3QNEalgHl8AZxoA3OvkjoOXZBMlHFoCkx0QjVyTRx8Gj9FcnRYADU6SE10NXFohWhITETk1NBxYgBfYjJKGnomVk9uAGVUSFImH1ljBWV89XsGpvRDNtAzCytWO0dqFzcPTm4fDIDyIJDQMIiogbpMIMw0gG0AXXnN7Z5oTUpQ8Mjqeep0PCcsPcOBu4esU-OR1evi0ooqLRGMxbA5nK53DVvFJQMEqIt7KAoS05P5uo0mAB1UiIPhQgAUgWClzWN1AQXcVE+lAA-CTrgYVnEWFQcPY6QUDgBKZ7zAjjR74gb+Rr2eE0NT4hgCYToAAiejo1ih-EEIhaAB9qjNkPUMWIpFzQABeaROaCkTDzfzgUh3Fg4HBYUh6dCQZAc-DQLLoQQDHmgAAydAiunmAJoTFQiHxMsw7mo1hY5WoUcQ0GoonYOuxkEgqtlmu1XlzkD1vR8kgDwdDdHDKbTscE8YlrGTgLTGazKpl6phWuzXnLzSkVbUNfwYYGEdT6GjPibiwTSYbc-TmcH3ALfekA6hw4NkjHQZDk7rAwY7jo1HxAfEB1uc8gwPxsVgLPu9med4fA1tiyFfx-FQO5MCaV1JRxe40kZIllh+KJQGvLw1GRQ0TWkL0fUEa1FFxUh7A4IQOUEZBcIUcBqGgHBkyWDkEOof00lALVSPmf9MFo4JAKAhQQOdBgINAQlWRghYlnpRDkO4VCdR8I1TVALCr3IcilD4AiiJI8gyOFRRKOorjCHoq4aCYlZTJuV57mgQUXDyNIA2U31yD+MpAUqZgJ10Vp-FvNRzUteZyBDdAOTFagKCEP5-GIDo21XaMuxhY1hOlNV8nEBTpEKdyKmBYtuFLbdD18vC0E6bRdH0Pl8HMSxrDGcEpjQ3xp0WYkLNJYK4lyFI0jcmdPMK5BSwPFEBg6NQuh6Jh+n8IYGtGMEJghaYvDmdqJK6hkNi2J5ORefw3lsj4zguHazJKYgQFATR7CigJEGIBhoHIMUkMalbJkhOTSOkVKDgAbiAA)). I'm not sure if there is a valid way to type and extend `Array` directly. If you can, it will be easier to type `MyIArray` if you compose it with `Array`--setting a property on `MyIArray` instances that is a vanilla array and then adding additional properties/methods to the `MyIArray`.